# Use an implicit TypeHandler based on resultType for select in MyBatis

Tags: java, jodatime, mybatis

I am trying to select a timestamp in MyBatis and return it as a LocalDateTime (from joda-time).

My configuration works fine if I try to return the result as a `java.sql.Timestamp`. I proved my type handler works fine: if I use a wrapping class with a `LocalDateTime` as only field and a resultMap in the MyBatis mapper file, I get the correct results.

However, when I try specifying the `org.joda.time.LocalDateTime` as `resultType` for this select, I always get `null`, as if the type handler is ignored.

It is my understanding that MyBatis uses a default typeHandler in the case I have `resultType="java.sql.Timestamp"`. As a consequence, I expected it to use one of the typeHandlers I configured when meeting `resultType="org.joda.time.LocalDateTime"`.

Did I miss something? Is there a way to make use of my typeHandler or am I forced to make a wrapper class and resultMap? This is my fallback-to solution but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

**mybatis-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <typeHandlers>
        <typeHandler javaType="org.joda.time.LocalDate" jdbcType="DATE" handler="...LocalDateTypeHandler"/>
        <typeHandler javaType="org.joda.time.LocalDateTime" jdbcType="TIMESTAMP" handler="...LocalDateTimeTypeHandler"/>
    </typeHandlers>
</configuration>
```

**NotifMailDao.java**

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;

public interface NotifMailDao {

    LocalDateTime getLastNotifTime(String userId);
}
```

**NotifMailDao.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="lu.bgl.notif.mail.dao.NotifMailDao">

    <select id="getLastNotifTime" resultType="org.joda.time.LocalDateTime">
        SELECT current_timestamp
        AS last_time
        FROM DUAL
    </select>
</mapper>
```

Comment: Hi @chop I'm facing the same issue and I'm still looking for an answer. You might probably get a faster reply if you post this to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mybatis-user. If you've already found a solution, do you mind adding it as an answer to your own question? Thanks!

Comment: Hello @Shobit. My workaround for now is to use a bean with only one field (the `LocalDateTime` I need) and a result map. Then the mapping works as expected. I guess what I am missing is a way to tell MyBatis that `current_timestamp` is a SQL `TIMESTAMP` type.

Comment: Yes, it seems that's the right way to do it. You could also use a resultMap with type='hashmap' rather than a bean (if you don't want to manage an extra bean just for this) See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mybatis-user/typehandler$20select$20column/mybatis-user/NehNStA-YIQ/c5dErmvI8WEJ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the TypeHandler configuration, MyBatis needs to know both the Java type of the resulting object and the SQL type of the source column.

Here we use a `resultType` in the `<select />` so MyBatis knows the Java type, but it cannot know the SQL type if we do not set it. The only way is to use a `<resultMap />`.

### The solution

You need to create a Bean with a single field containing the object you want to return (let us call this field `time`) and use a `<resultMap />`:

```
<select id="getLastNotifTime" resultMap="notifMailResultMap">
```

---

```
<resultMap id="mapLastTime" type="MyWrapperBean">
    <result property="time" column="my_sql_timestamp" javaType="org.joda.time.LocalDateTime"
        jdbcType="TIMESTAMP" />
</resultMap>
```

If you wish to spare the creation of dedicated bean, you can also use the attribute `type=hashmap` on your `<resultMap />` as suggested by [Shobit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30307031/#comment49245248_30307031).

### Variant: set the property on the `LocalDateTime`

A [solution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mybatis-user/1RN24rBcdo8/Oc1gm_HAIW0J) has been proposed on Google Groups, which sets directly the information on the `LocalDateTime`.

My understanding of it (please comment if I am wrong) is that it sets a property of the `LocalDateTime`. I will not vouch for it as I do not find the corresponding in the [API doc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) (and I have not tested it) but feel free to use it if you deem it better.

```
<resultMap id="mapLastTime" type="org.joda.time.LocalDateTime">
    <result property="lastTime" column="my_sql_timestamp" javaType="org.joda.time.LocalDateTime"
        jdbcType="TIMESTAMP" />
</resultMap>
```

### Why it works with `java.sql.Timestamp`

`Timestamp` is a standard Java type for SQL, with a default JDBC implementation ([`ResultSet.getTimestamp(int/String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp(int))). The default handler for MyBatis uses this getter<sup>1</sup> and therefore does not need any TypeHandler mapping. I expect this occurs every time you use one of the default handlers.

---

<sub>1: This is a hunch. Citation required!</sub>

**This answer only awaits to be replaced with something better. Please contribute!**

Comment: Do you have the java code variant for spring ? How to I load these resultMap ?

Comment: I'm sorry, @BigDong. It's been quite a while since last time I used MyBatis, I don't remember all the details. The result map is part of the MyBatis configuration. There is one in my answer (see the XML starting with `<resultMap`). I don't know what you call the "java code variant for Spring", this is all my MyBatis mapper file. Read more about mapper files and result maps [here](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html) and about using mappers in Spring [here](http://www.mybatis.org/spring/mappers.html).